# typeRoots not found in tsconfig.json in angular 10

Tags: angular, tsconfig

I want to update typeRoots in tsconfig.json in angular 10
but typeRoots is not showing in my tsconfig.json file
how to solve this

Regards
Baiju

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `typeRoots` to the `compilerOptions` in your tsconfig.json, see the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["./typings", "./vendor/types"]
  }
}
```